# Magento 2 Load - Block (CMS Static Block in Magento 1 terms)

Tags: magento2, cms-block

I am attempting to load a static block from my controller - but am having trouble locating the right syntax for doing this.

What is the proper syntax to load a CMS block by identifier or block id and what factory supports this type of loading?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On  *__construct* function,you need inject

- `\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider`
- `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`
- `\Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory`

for getting data.

**You can try below as example**

> ```
> .......
>     public function __construct(
>         \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
>         \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
>         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
>         \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
>         array $data = []
>     ) {
>         parent::__construct($context, $data);
>         $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
>         $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
>         $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
>     }
>
>
>     protected function content()
>     {
>         $blockId = 'YOurBlock_Id';
>         $html = '';
>         if ($blockId) {
>             $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
>             /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
>             $block = $this->_blockFactory->create();
>             $block->setStoreId($storeId)->load($blockId);
>
>                 $html = $this->_filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->setStoreId($storeId)->filter($block->getContent());
>         }
>         return   $html;
> ```
>
> }